# Where can I find the Biotic Amp Interface?

Tags: mass-effect-3

As I was walking through Huerta Memorial in *Mass Effect 3*, I overheard an Asari talking about a Biotic Amp Interface that could be beneficial to the war effort. I seem to remember hearing her say the interface was at Grissom Academy, but I've searched there pretty thoroughly and haven't found them.

**Am I looking in the right place? If not, where can this item be found?**

Comment: I *did* find it in Grissom Academy. On a console, I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface is at Grissom Academy. Do not worry if you could not find it, though, such objects will become available at the Spectre Requisitions Office after you miss them, and will be generally sold for a measly 1000 credits.